# Integrity Error *_id may not be null

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Python and Django so please forgive my ignorance.

I am receiving the following error when saving a formset

```
IntegrityError at /jobs/1/
jobs_education.applicant_id may not be NULL
```

Here is the my view:

```
def application(request, job_id):
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_id)
    #return 404 if job isn't yet published
    if (job.pub_date>timezone.now()):
    return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Job not found</h1>')


    EducationInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Applicant, Education, extra=1, can_delete=False)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApplicantForm(request.POST)
        formset = EducationInlineFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            # save the model to database, directly from the form:
            applicant_saved = form.save()
            formset.applicant_id = applicant_saved.id
            print 'formset %s' % formset.__dict__
            formset.save()
            return render(request, 'jobs/success.html')


    else:
        applicant = Applicant(job=job)
        form = ApplicantForm(instance=applicant)
        formset = EducationInlineFormSet(instance=applicant)

    c = { 
    'form' : form ,
    'formset' : formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'jobs/test.html', c)
```

As you can see, i am not manually trying to set the applicant_id of the formset but it isn't making a difference.

The output of:

```
print 'formset %s' % formset.__dict__
```

is

```
{'auto_id': u'id_%s', 'is_bound': True, 'initial_extra': None, 'error_class': <class 'django.forms.util.ErrorList'>, 'save_as_new': False, '_non_form_errors': [], 'initial': None, 'queryset': [], '_pk_field': <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, 'forms': [<django.forms.models.EducationForm object at 0x1014078d0>], 'instance': <Applicant: >, 'prefix': u'education_set', 'applicant_id': 4, 'data': <QueryDict: {u'education_set-0-date': [u'1989-05-19'], u'education_set-0-school': [u'asdf'], u'education_set-0-grade': [u'oi'], u'telephone': [u'mlk'], u'nationality': [u'lk'], u'address_postcode': [u'lk'], u'address_line2': [u'lkm'], u'address_line1': [u'm'], u'education_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], u'applicant_dob': [u'1989-05-14'], u'address_district': [u'lkm'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'3tfdnCwqYSWkyoTjEBX6peUVCGRANSKj'], u'email': [u'lkm@c.com'], u'national_insurance_number': [u'mlk'], u'address_county': [u'lkm'], u'job': [u'1'], u'address_town': [u'lkm'], u'education_set-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'0'], u'education_set-0-town': [u'sdf'], u'education_set-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'1'], u'applicant_name': [u'asd'], u'education_set-0-applicant': [u''], u'mobile': [u'm'], u'education_set-0-id': [u''], u'applicant_surname': [u'klm'], u'education_set-0-qualification': [u'oj']}>, '_errors': [{}], 'files': {}}
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide you with.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

edit:

Adding my models here as someone is bound to ask for them

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.location_name

class Job(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title

class Applicant(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    applicant_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    applicant_surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    applicant_dob = models.DateField('Date of Birth')
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    national_insurance_number=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address_line1=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_line2=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_district=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_town=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_county=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_postcode=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telephone=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    mobile=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    approved=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.applicant_name
    def isApproved(self):
        return self.approved
    def approve(self):
        self.approved = True

class Education(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant)
    school=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    town=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date=models.DateField('date')
    qualification=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grade=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.school
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formset is a set of forms. It doesn't have an applicant ID. Trying to set one doesn't make sense.

You're actually almost doing the right thing already. In the GET block you're correctly passing the `instance` argument to the formset instantiation, to associate it with an Applicant. But you're not doing that in the POST block, and you should be:

```
    form = ApplicantForm(request.POST, instance=applicant)
    formset = EducationInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=applicant)
```

Comment: I knew I was close. Thanks for your correct, speedy and not condescending answer!